# Managed authentication roles in spring boot and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication

I have a bit trouble finding out how i can managed my authentication roles on the front end. I want to access the authentication role and pass it to the root scope but it returns an array instead.

I want to know which role the user has add some privilege to each roles.
How could this be done ?

If i call user /user

```
{"details":{"remoteAddress":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","sessionId":"1F64CC142A715A53FFF4A9329E6B933D"},"authorities":[{"authority":"USER_ROLE"}],"authenticated":true,"principal":{"password":null,"username":"1@1","authorities":[{"authority":"USER_ROLE"}],"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"enabled":true},"credentials":null,"name":"1@1"}
```

This is my login controller :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);


    LoginController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route','$localStorage'];
    function LoginController($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $route,$localStorage) {


        $scope.tab = function(route) {
            return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
        };


        var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

            var headers = credentials ? {
                authorization : "Basic "
                + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                    + credentials.password)
            } : {};


            $http.get('user/', {
                headers : headers
            }).success(function(data) {
                if (data.name) {

                    //This returns an array...
                    console.log(data.authorities);

                    console.log("Good Credentials");
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                } else {

                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                }
                callback && callback($rootScope.authenticated);
            }).error(function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                callback && callback(false);
            });

        };

        authenticate();

        $scope.credentials = {};
        $scope.login = function() {
            authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated) {
                if (authenticated) {
                    console.log("Login succeeded");
                    console.log($scope.credentials.username);
                    $location.path("/app/dashboard");
                    $scope.error = false;
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;

                    //Here we add all the variables we need to the session that are safe to be seen
                    //In the future we can replace this and load this in the splash screen every time the application loads so we are sure the
                    // variables are stored



                } else {
                    console.log("Login failed")
                    $location.path("/login");
                    $scope.error = true;
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                }
            })
        };



        //Logout
        $scope.logout = function() {
            $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                $location.path("/");
            }).error(function(data) {
                $location.path("/");
                console.log("Logout failed")
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            });
        }







    }

})();
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public Principal user(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Spring documentation, [@AuthenticationPrincipal](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/bind/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html) will return value to the `Authentication.getPrincipal()`.  However, if you look at [Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html), you will see that the authorities of the user are accessed separately from the principal, using `Authentication.getAuthorities()`.

You can do a couple of things, either modify your custom `Principal` to also include the roles of the users, or you can also grab the authorities and serialize them in addition to the principal within your controller.

You can get the current authentication via:  `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`